# Is it possible to make a function return a generic collection of generic type

Tags: java, generics, collections

The input to a function are the following

1. File path
2. Collection class
3. Element class

```
public <E, C extends Collection> C<E> readCollectionFromFile(String filePath,
Class<C> collectionClass, Class<E> elementClass) {

// read from file and return a collection of type C having elements of type E 

}
```

For example if

1. `collectionClass = HashSet` and `elementClass = Integer` -> Function should return `HashSet<Integer>`
2. `collectionClass = ArrayList` and `elementClass = String` -> Function should return `ArrayList<String>`

Comment: Yes it is possible.

Comment: Just return `Collection<E>`.

Comment: Do you have to use Class arguments?  It would be far better to accept [Supplier](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/Supplier.html) and [Function](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/Function.html) arguments.  Using Class arguments, your method will have to make an unsafe cast.

Comment: The correct declaration would be `public <E, C extends Collection<E>> C readCollection…` but then, the caller will have a hard time passing an appropriate `Class` object (`ArrayList.class` or `HashSet.class` will not work as intended due to type erasure). As @VGR said, it’s much better to replace `Class<C> collectionClass` with `Supplier<C> collectionSupplier`. Then, the caller can use `ArrayList::new` or `HashSet::new` which works smoothly with generics.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, this is possible. For example, you can save a generic collection to a file using serialization and then read it back into an object:

```java
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashSet;;

public class Main
{

    public static <E,C extends Collection<E>> Object readCollectionFromFile(String filePath) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException
    {
        try(ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(filePath)))
        {
            return ((C)ois.readObject());
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, ClassNotFoundException, IOException
    {
        Main.<Integer,HashSet<Integer>>readCollectionFromFile("example.ser");
    }

}
```